# How to select multiple DIVs by mousedown>mousemove>mouseup (pure JS)

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to make a selection of elements when I click on empty point and move pointer.

In this example I'm expecting to get selection of two elements:

[image]

I've tried range and selection, but not with the proper result.

```js
const mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
mainDiv.style.width = "500px";
mainDiv.style.height = "500px";
document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);

const div1 = document.createElement("div");
div1.style.position = "absolute";
div1.style.top = `${50}px`;
div1.style.left = `${50}px`;
div1.style.width = "100px";
div1.style.height = "100px";
div1.style.background = "red";
mainDiv.appendChild(div1);

const div2 = document.createElement("div");
div2.style.top = `${250}px`;
div2.style.left = `${250}px`;
div2.style.width = "100px";
div2.style.height = "100px";
div2.style.background = "green";
div2.style.position = "absolute";
mainDiv.appendChild(div2);

mainDiv.onmousedown = function(event) {
  function onMouseMove(event) {
    //add divs to selection
  }
  mainDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

  mainDiv.onmouseup = function() {
    console.log("selected divs")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by keeping an array of selected items and pushing items to it when the mouse moves over the items if the mouse is depressed.

```js
const mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
mainDiv.style.width = "500px";
mainDiv.style.height = "500px";
document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);

const div1 = document.createElement("div");
div1.style.position = "absolute";
div1.style.top = `${50}px`;
div1.style.left = `${50}px`;
div1.style.width = "100px";
div1.style.height = "100px";
div1.style.background = "red";
mainDiv.appendChild(div1);

const div2 = document.createElement("div");
div2.style.top = `${250}px`;
div2.style.left = `${250}px`;
div2.style.width = "100px";
div2.style.height = "100px";
div2.style.background = "green";
div2.style.position = "absolute";
mainDiv.appendChild(div2);


!(() => {
  let selection = [];
  let selecting = false;
  function beginSelection(e) {
    selection = [];
    selecting = true;
    checkSelection(e);
  }
  function mouseMove(e) {
    checkSelection(e);
  }
  function mouseUp(e) {
    selecting = false;
    if (selection.length) {
      console.log("selection: ", selection); // access selection before reset
      selection = [];
    } else {
      // no selection
    }
  }
  function checkSelection(e) {
    if (!selecting) {
      return; // ignore
    }
    const selected = e.target.parentNode === mainDiv && e.target;
    if (selected && !selection.includes(selected)) {
      selection.push(selected);
    }
  }
  mainDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", beginSelection);
  mainDiv.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
  
})();
```